# removing upper part of a wall

Tags: walls

i would like to remove the upper part of that wall, the cut would be somewhere between the red line

one thing i want to make sure is to NOT damage the firewood side finish, the rock tile.

what would be the best way to do that? also assume the remaining section of the wall could need more support, i would like some advice on that too

[image: the wall]

Comment: That's a pretty vague question. Are you asking for a tutorial on general carpentry, or do you have something more specific that's troubling you?

Comment: Also, what's going to hold the wall up?

Comment: @isherwood the wall is nailed to the floor, joist and the wall at the end, i want to cut the wall between the red line and remove the whole upper part. what will be left remaining is the lower part of the wall only. i think i need to add block between the stud under the cut and maybe adding more nail to secure the wall to the floor and at the end. Goal is to make sure the rock tile doesnt get damaged. if it does, i will simply remove the whole wall. i hope I don't have to do that. (english is not my first language, sorry if my explanation is hard to understand)

Comment: Your explanation is clear enough (with better English than most Americans), but you're still asking a very broad question and I don't think you have a good plan to hold the wall up. That usually requires either a post to the ceiling or a post anchored in the floor system or slab.

Comment: the floor, this is in a basement. it have the cement floor, a grid of 2x3 and particleboard. I can make sure the wall is properly nailed to these 2x3. hoping that it will remove any possible wobble.

Comment: It absolutely will not eliminate wobble. Like I said, a post is required.

Comment: Nobody has mentioned the steel post or wall jack at the  near end of the wall. ??

Comment: @AlaskaMan That steel post doesn't appear in the other photo, so I think it is not part of the wall. It's probably aligned with the beam, so is a foot of so away from the wall in question. And probably a foot or so in the direction of the camera, too.

Comment: @AlaskaMan, the steel post is not attached to the wall, if you look at the cat litter in both picture, it's about 3 feet away from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can remove the upper part of that wall by:

1. Scoring the drywall on the finished side where you want the cut to be.
2. Removing the drywall from the top portion taking care not to pull off any below the score line.
3. Cutting the studs along that line and removing the top portion of each one.
4. Place some top plate on top of the remaining studs to tie them all together.

Ok, now you have done what you asked but your going to be left with a wobbly and weakly supported half-wall.  It was not designed or built to stand on its own and you will likely not be satisfied with it. I will say that I don't believe it's possible to secure a 2x4 wall by attaching only at the bottom.

Free standing half walls are usually deeper than a normal floor-to-ceiling wall and they are often secured through the floor and to the floor joists for stability.

I think your plan needs to be revisited.

What to do?  You need to somehow provide a secure anchor to keep the remaining

Comment: right now the wall is in fact 2x3 not 2x4. Maybe a stupid idea, doubling the width of the wall (something like building a second wall right next to the current one) would it help? or even wider, i can use some spaces on the cat litter side if needed. so i could maybe create a kind of small countertop

Comment: A doubled wall would help, especially if you used construction adhesive and screws on every joint at the bottom of the wall (studs to plate, plate to floor). A more common approach is to leave a doubled stud running to the ceiling as a post. Is it important that you have a wide open area at the end of the wall?

Comment: @isherwood, i would need to think about leaving the stud at the end of the wall, that is something i didn't think. that might be one more option, i'm not sure how to finish it so it look "good"

Comment: You'd wrap it with drywall like you presumably will do for the top of the half wall. It's just a very short wall itself.